# combine more than one rows into a single JSON Object based on common column value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have the following table :

```
id |   model    |  version   |   status
_________________________________________

.. |  model1    |   1.0      |    old
.. |  model1    |   2.0      |    new
.. |  model2    |   1.1      |    old
.. |  model2    |   1.2      |    new
```

I need to generate JSON object based on the status for same model(combine two rows into single JSON object) like below :

```
[
   {
      "model" : "model1",
      "old_version" : "1.0",
      "new_version" : "2.0"
   },
   {
      "model" : "model2",
      "old_version" : "1.1",
      "new_version" : "1.2"
   }
]
```

What I tried so far :

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(t."model",
                                  CASE WHEN t."status" == 'new'
                                   THEN 'new_version',t."version",
                                  end 
                                   CASE WHEN t."status" == 'old'
                                   THEN 'old_version',t."version",
                                  end ))
from (// my select query with various conditions goes here) t
```

I am getting syntax error also. How can I achieve the expected output

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `THEN` part of a CASE expression can only contain a single expression, so `then value_a, value_b end` is not valid. You are also missing an key for the `model` value.

However, you have a two stage aggregation here: first aggregate the versions per model, then aggregate that result into an array. As aggregate functions can't be nested, you need a derived table for this:

This aggregates the versions for each model:

```
select jsonb_build_object('model', model)||jsonb_object_agg(status||'_version', version)
from (...)
group by model
```

If you can't or don't want to use the status name as the prefix for the "version key", you will have to use a CASE expression:

```
select jsonb_build_object('model', model)|| 
              jsonb_object_agg(case status 
                                 when 'old' then 'old_version' 
                                 when 'new' then 'new_version' 
                               end, 
                               version)
from (...)
group by model
```

This can then be used in a derived table to get the json array:

```
select jsonb_agg(model)
from (
  select jsonb_build_object('model', model)||jsonb_object_agg(status||'_version', version) as model
  from (...)
  group by model
) t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cda5e085dce2446d6b7ed035e5cd0d86)

Comment: As u have used OR operator, will it not give two JSON objects for each model? I want a single JSON object with both version values and model value

Comment: @code-geek: I don't understand what you are referring to. There is no OR in my query.

Comment: i mean am not getting the expected JSON array. It adds an extra key as model and the value is the JSON object with three keys. Instead I want an array with direclty the JSON object with three keys

Comment: Please see the online example it returns exactly the value you want

Comment: This is the query that I framed. JSON objects are built as expected but I am facing issue (extra key added) while doing aggregate. Please help me where I am doing wrong

Comment: select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(t1) )
from (select jsonb_build_object('model', t."model")||jsonb_object_agg(case t."status" 
                                 when 'old' then 'old_version' 
                                 when 'new' then 'new_version' 
                               end, t."version") 
from (SELECT * FROM "TABLE"
 JOIN unnest(string_to_array('model1,model2,model3 ',')) t1(c1) ON "model" = t1.c1
 JOIN unnest(string_to_array('old,new', ',')) t2(c2) ON "status" = t2.c2) t group by t."model") t1

Comment: @horse_with_no_name Thank you very much. I  corrected few syntax errors and now it is working perfect. Thank you!